# Kind of files which just have extension, like .bashrc or .cshrc

Tags: filenames, history, dot-files

I'm wondering about files that have a name starting with a dot e.g.

`.bashrc` or `.cshrc` have distinct feature? (Could we say `.bashrc` extension?)

Maybe these kind of files are a member of a category?

Why are these files named in this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Linux and Unix in general, files do not have extensions. The entire "text" is a filename.

If a filename starts with a dot ".", it means the file is hidden. I.e. it will not be shown when the content of the directory is listed unless specifically asked for.

Comment: These are often called « dotfiles » by convention.

Comment: "hiding" the files starting with `.` is specifically a feature of `ls` (unless `-a`) and of the path expansion ("globbing"; unless `dotglob`/`GLOB_PERIOD`); otherwise those files will be always shown without having to ask for; the OS does not hide them.

Comment: @mosvy and other tools. Such as a GUI file browser.

Comment: In linux dot is just a character of the filename, in dos/windows it is a delimiter between the filename and it's extension. So, in Linux a file can have several dots, if it starts with a dot it is not shown by `ls` three filenames are predefined `/` root or filename-delimiter, `.` cwd & `..` parent of cwd.

Answer (score 1):

## A history note:

This all came about because of a bug.

It an early implementation of `ls`, the developer decided not to display the directories `.` and `..` by default. They thought that an easy way to do that (probably with memory constraints), would be to check the first character, only display if not a dot. Other users noticed this bug, and used it to hide file. From this moment on, it was a feature.

## Why hide them?

Because there are many config files, and most of the time you don't want to be bothered by them.

## That is the `rc` all about.

This is a file extension (just some extra characters), it denotes it as a configuration file.

## So does Unix have file extensions.

Yes: you can add extra character to a file name. Some programs will use these extra characters, to know how to process the file e.g. A file manager uses it to know which app to launch.

No: It is just part of the file name. (in DOS and CP/M a file-name may be encoded as `filenametxt`, but be displayed as `filename.txt`. Those days are long gone, but live a sort of zombie existence in MS-Windows ).

Answer (score 0):

The other answer is accurate, but part of what you asked was "why are these files named this way?"

In the context of working with the Linux OS, the answer is naming conventions.

It isn't known to the OS or shell, but to the users.  RC is shorthand for resource control, .conf is common for configuration files, .sh is common for shell scripts, .pl for perl, .py for python, etc.

It is only when you get to applications, such a apache, where the extension matters.
File extensions are mapped to Mime/application types by the web server.  So .php allows the file to be pre-processed by the PHP module before it is handed back to apache to send as a resultant HTML document.  But on the command line with php, you could technically use php to run a script ending in .py or .sh or even .txt